# Python: Iterate a range of numbers as input for Plotly Dash

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am currently working on Plotly Dash on Python. Here is a sample of my code:

```
    html.Div([
        html.Div([html.Label('View max selection')]),
        dcc.Slider(
            id   = 'view-max-bar',
            min  = 10,
            max  = 500,
            value= 10,
            step = 10,
            marks= {10: '10', 20: '20', 30: '30', 40: '40', 50: '50'}
    )], style = {'display' : 'inline-block', 'width': '50%', 'margin-top': '10px'})
```

My intention is to assign `marks` from range 10 to 500 with steps of 10 to `dcc.Slider`. I can type the values out one by one but it will be lengthy and inefficient. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement something like this code before your dash code:

```
counter = 0

marksList = []

marks = {}

while counter < 500:
    counter = counter +10
    marksList.append(counter)
   
for i in range(len(marksList)):
    marks[marksList[i]] = str(marksList[i])
```

What it is doing is using the `while` loop, it is making a list of a counter which increased by 10, all the way to 500, and the `for` statement is using every number in the list of the counters and making the key value pair necessary for the argument of marks in the dash code. The dictionary `marks` looks like this:

```
{10: '10', 20: '20', 30: '30', 40: '40', 50: '50', 60: '60', 70: '70', 80: '80', 90: '90', 100: '100', 110: '110', 120: '120', 130: '130', 140: '140', 150: '150', 160: '160', 170: '170', 180: '180', 190: '190', 200: '200', 210: '210', 220: '220', 230: '230', 240: '240', 250: '250', 260: '260', 270: '270', 280: '280', 290: '290', 300: '300', 310: '310', 320: '320', 330: '330', 340: '340', 350: '350', 360: '360', 370: '370', 380: '380', 390: '390', 400: '400', 410: '410', 420: '420', 430: '430', 440: '440', 450: '450', 460: '460', 470: '470', 480: '480', 490: '490', 500: '500'}
```

From here, you can simply just put the dictionary `marks` are the value for the variable marks in the dash argument.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for a python feature called dict comprehension. Instead of

`marks= {10: '10', 20: '20', 30: '30', 40: '40', 50: '50'}`

you can write

`marks = {i:str(i) for i in range(10,51,10)}`

where the arguments to range are `(start, stop, step)`, `stop` being exclusive (hence the `51` to include `50`). So to go to 500:

`marks = {i:str(i) for i in range(10,501,10)}`